# How to apply 2 filters drawtext and drawbox using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm having problems combining filters.  I'm trying to take video from the camera, apply a timer on it and also overlay a box in the center.  I can put a time code (local time and pts) using the -vf drawtext command no problems:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 \
-vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: \
text='%{localtime} %{pts\:hms}':  fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: \
boxcolor=black@0.8: boxborderw=5: x=0: y=0" -vcodec libx264 \
-preset ultrafast -f mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y output.mp4
```

Then I have one that draws a small box using drawbox:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 \
-filter_complex " drawbox=x=iw/2:y=0:w=10:h=ih:color=red@0.1": \
-vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -f mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y output.mp4
```

I assumed I could combine these with the filter_complex switch and separate them using the semicolon like this

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: text='%{localtime} %{pts\:hms}':  fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.8;drawbox=x=iw/2:y=0:w=10:h=ih:color=red@0.1": -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -f mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y output.mp4
```

But it fails to find the input stream on the second filter:

> Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
>
> Duration: N/A, start: 10651.720690, bitrate: N/A
>
> Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, -5 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
>
> Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_drawbox_1

I tried to direct it to [0] like this:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -filter_complex " \
drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: \
text='%{localtime} %{pts\:hms}':  fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: \
boxcolor=black@0.8;[0] drawbox=x=iw/2:y=0:w=10:h=ih:color=red@0.1": \
-vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -f mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y output.mp4
```

But it fails to put the box on the output.

So I tried to split streams like this

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -filter_complex " \
split [main][tmp];\
[main] drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: \
text='%{localtime} %{pts\:hms}':  fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.8 [tmp];\
[main] drawbox=x=iw/2:y=0:w=10:h=ih:color=red@0.1 [tmp2]; [tmp][tmp2] overlay": \
-vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -f mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y output.mp4
```

But my build doesn't have the overlay filter complied with it.  At this point I decided to stop and ask if I'm making this harder than it should be.  The end result is I just want a timer and a box drawn on the video.  Is there a better way or a formatting trick to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just apply them one after the another, by separating via a comma.

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -filter_complex " \
drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: \
text='%{localtime} %{pts\:hms}':  fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: \
boxcolor=black@0.8, drawbox=x=iw/2:y=0:w=10:h=ih:color=red@0.1": \
-vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -f mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but I was under the impression that the semicolon was supposed to do this, not the comma.

Comment: I did.  That's where it points out the use of multiple filters using a semi-colon.

Comment: It says, "*Filters in the same linear chain are separated by commas, and distinct linear chains of filters are separated by semicolons.*". drawtext and drawbox are not in distinct chains.