# FFMPEG Trying to downscale an 8K video to 4k while adding boxes on the sides and bottom in one command

Tags: ffmpeg, scale

I am taking an very high quality 8k video and I want to try to get as good a 4k video out of it as possible. But at the same time I want to remove the sides of the video as well as the bottom, but not the top, making almost a 'T' shaped video, like so:

[image]

As I understand it it should be possible for me to do all of this in one command but I am running into some trouble. Here is the command(s) I have tried:

First one is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282823/how-to-apply-multiple-filters-and-inputs-with-ffmpeg) post:

```
ffmpeg -i "8k.test.mp4" -preset slow -vcodec libx265 -crf 18 -movflags faststart -filter_complex "[1]scale=3840:2160 [2]drawbox=w=384:h=1280:x=0:y=640:t=fill,drawbox=w=384:h=1280:x=3840-384:y=640:t=fill,drawbox=w=3840:h=300:x=0:y=2160-300:t=fill" -an -c:a copy output.mp4
```

**Error**

> [AVFilterGraph @ 0000029c747cf540] Unable to parse graph description substring: "drawbox=w=384:h=1280:x=0:y=640:t=fill,drawbox=w=384:h=1280:x=3840-384:y=640:t=fill,drawbox=w=3840:h=300:x=0:y=2160-300:t=fill"
> Error initializing complex filters.
> Invalid argument

---

Second one is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000183/how-to-apply-2-filters-drawtext-and-drawbox-using-ffmpeg) post:

```
ffmpeg -i "8k.test.mp4" -preset slow -vcodec libx265 -crf 18 -movflags faststart -vf scale=3840:2160, drawbox=w=384:h=1280:x=0:y=640:t=fill,drawbox=w=384:h=1280:x=3840-384:y=640:t=fill,drawbox=w=3840:h=300:x=0:y=2160-300:t=fill -an -c:a copy output.mp4
```

**Error:**

> [NULL @ 000001f5ee5d1500] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'drawbox=w=384:h=1280:x=0:y=640:t=fill,drawbox=w=384:h=1280:x=3840-384:y=640:t=fill,drawbox=w=3840:h=300:x=0:y=2160-300:t=fill'
> drawbox=w=384:h=1280:x=0:y=640:t=fill,drawbox=w=384:h=1280:x=3840-384:y=640:t=fill,drawbox=w=3840:h=300:x=0:y=2160-300:t=fill: Invalid argument

---

I seem to be misunderstanding something, according to the documentation commands in same catgegory should be seperated by 'comma' and different category by 'semicolon'. But I have tried both to no avail.

> Filters in the same linear chain are separated by commas, and distinct linear chains of filters are separated by semicolons.

from [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction).

Would anyone know how to get about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I found the solution, I was putting spaces after the comma, this way causing issues.

The correct command was as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i <INPUT>.mp4 -preset slow -vcodec libx265 -crf 18 -movflags faststart -vf scale=3840:2160,drawbox=w=450:h=1280:x=0:y=640:t=fill,drawbox=w=450:h=1280:x=3840-450:y=640:t=fill,drawbox=w=3840:h=400:x=0:y=2160-400:t=fill -an -c:a copy <OUTPUT>.mp4
```

However, a side note in my use case that perhaps someone can try and explain.

If I run the above command I will get a video file that has really good quality and the boxes the way I want them but with a file size of 350MB for 20 seconds.

However if I run the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i <INPUT-FILE> -vf scale=3840:2160 -preset slow -vcodec libx265 -crf 0 -movflags faststart -an -c:a copy <OUTPUT-NAME>.mp4
```

And then follow it with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i <INPUT-FILE> -vf drawbox=w=450:h=1280:x=0:y=640:t=fill,drawbox=w=450:h=1280:x=3840-450:y=640:t=fill,drawbox=w=3840:h=400:x=0:y=2160-400:t=fill -c:a copy <OUTPUT-NAME>.mp4
```

Then I get a file that is only 106MB yet the quality difference is negligable. I am happy that I have run all these tests because in my case I would much rather want a file that is under a third of the size with quality that is hard to distinguish.

I use https://www.diffchecker.com/image-diff/ to check the difference.

Comment: Enclose your filtergraph in double quotes and you can have all the spaces you want: `-vf "filter1, filter2,                              filter3,     filter4"`